# Hadoop aggregating two function

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

i have the following file:

```
Item1 : frequencyOfItem1
Item2 : frequencyOfItem2
...
ItemN : frequencyOfItemN
```

after some lines i have...

```
Pair1: Item1, Item2  Value1
Pari2: ItemX, ItemY  Value2
```

....

```
PairN: ItemXN, ItemYN ValueN
```

I would like to calculate in map-reduce way the following new-value as this:

```
ParirX: ItemX, ItemY ValueX/FrequencyItemNX
```

How do i map and reduce the values for do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possibile to solve this by doing 2 jobs combined

1. Mapper: in the mapper the key is ItemX and value all the other elements
2. Reducer: output all the values (in this way I'm concatenating the values based on the ItemX

job2

2. Mapper two keys, one key the entire line and the value is ValueX and second key the entire line and value is FrequencyItemNX
3. Reducer output the divisione between the values of the keys

Comment: Oops. Numbers are messed up. Anyways. You could probably solve this differently with a Custom Writable class

Comment: you can provide and example of your solution please ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't written mapreduce in years, but I'm just "thinking out loud"